# "Discretizing" an infinite dimensional path integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, path-integral, discrete

Consider the free scalar field generating functional

\begin{align}
Z&=\int\!D\varphi\, e^{ -\frac{i}{2}\int\!d^4x\, \varphi(\partial^2+m^2)\varphi +J\varphi  }\\
&:=\lim\limits_{N\to\infty}\left(  \prod^{N-1}_{k=1} \int d\varphi_k \right)  \exp\left[ -\frac{i}{2}\int\!d^4x\, \varphi(\partial^2+m^2)\varphi +J\varphi\right].
\end{align}

To solve this infinite dimensional path integral, I will pretend there are a finite number of $\varphi_k$.  I will implement this by letting $N$ be some finite number instead of taking its infinite limit.  This will allow me to use a standard Gaussian integral formula.  I will replace $\varphi(\partial^2+m^2)\varphi\to\sum_{m,n}\varphi_mA_{mn}\varphi_n$, and I'll do the same for the source term with $J$ in it.  Using the convention that repeated indices are summed, we have

\begin{align}
 Z&\to C\!\int \!d\varphi_1\,d\varphi_2\dots d\varphi_{N-1} \exp \left[-\frac{i}{2} \varphi_mA_{mn}\varphi_n + J_k\varphi_k   \right]\\
&=C\!\int \!d\varphi_1\,d\varphi_2\dots d\varphi_{N-1} \exp \left[-\frac{i}{2} \varphi\cdot A\cdot\varphi + J\cdot\varphi   \right]
\end{align}

This integral appears in a table I have.

Here is my question: Although $\varphi_m$ would normally have $N$ components $\{ \varphi_1,\varphi_2,\dots,\varphi_N \}$, by direct employment of the definition of the path integral I have discretized $\varphi$ to have $N-1$ components $\{ \varphi_1,\varphi_2,\dots,\varphi_{N-1} \}$.  Is that right?  I am using Zee's text book, 2nd Ed., and on page 22 when he discretizes it gets $N$ copies of $d\varphi_k$ instead of the $N-1$ copies I have here.  I think since $N$ is just some random finite number, he has moved to a convention in which $\varphi_k$ has $N$ components, as per usual.  I just want to make sure that what I've done is exactly the same by preserving the $N-1$ in the definition of $\int D\varphi$ as long as I take $\varphi_k$ to have $N-1$ components.  Is this sound?  Just trying to make sure I understand.

Comment: Whether you have $N$ or $N-1$ just depends how many time slices you took in the first place. I agree that your original definition suggests $N-1$ time slices but you could always relabel $M=N-1$ if you just don't want to carry around the minus ones in your algebra.

Comment: @jacob1729 I want to confirm that the number of time slices and components in the sums in the exponential are the same (bc we're talking about an oscillator at each slice, I believe.) If I had $N-1$ integrals over $d\varphi_k$, then there cant be a sum $\sum_1^NJ_k\varphi_k$ in the exponential, right? The sum would be $\sum_1^{N-1}J_k\varphi_k$. This is what I'm trying to confirm. I think its obvious because I couldnt leave one $\varphi_k$ in the exponent not integrated over but I want someone to confirm. The $d\varphi_k$ labels are the same labels on the $\varphi_k$ in the exponential, right?